# How do I make a Python async named pipe server using curio?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, async-await, curio

How do you create an asynchronous named pipe server with [Dave Beazley's curio library](https://github.com/dabeaz/curio)? If not that one, is there any library faster and/or more intuitive to use than Python's default asyncio library that I could easily us to write an asynchronous named pipe server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer seems to be that, for now, you don't. You can do it with Python's built in `asyncio` though, but only if you use `asyncio.windows_events.ProactorEventLoop` as your event loop. And that event loop can't also handle stdin and stdout, so you're forced into using two threads if your program needs to stay responsive to user input.